# MVC Redirect from helper class with TempData

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, tempdata

In my _Layout.cshtml I have a few div's for displaying messages.

```
<div>@TempData["SuccessMessage"]</div>
<div>@TempData["WarningMessage"]</div>
<div>@TempData["ErrorMessage"]</div>
```

I am trying to created a global redirect helper class to display these messages:

MessageHelper.cs

```
public static RedirectResult RedirectWithMessage(Controller controller, string messagetype, string url, string message)
{
    controller.ViewData[messagetype] = message;
    return (new RedirectResult(url));
}
```

From my controller:

```
return RedirectWithMessage(this, "SuccessMessage", "~/good", "Looks good");
return RedirectWithMessage(this, "WarningMessage", "~/warning", "Ooops a warning");
return RedirectWithMessage(this, "ErrorMessage", "~/error", "Danger an error");
```

I get the redirect fine but the no message from TempData.

I have done this successfully from within the Controller using:

```
private RedirectResult RedirectWithMessage(string messagetype, string url, string message)
{
    TempData[messagetype] = message;
    return Redirect(url);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated ...

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried:

```
controller.TempData[messagetype] = message;
```

`ViewData` is not what your layout is looking for.

Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: That was it.  Simple.  That's what happens when you have a 16 hour coding session.  You start overlooking the simplest things.  Thank you.

Comment: When you get a chance, please Upvote and select it as the right answer. This encourages folks to contribute